# How to stop the execution of jq function till the user confirmation in dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just need to stop execution of function until the user conform OK or CANCEL in dialog box. If user clicks on OK it should continue the execution ..if he clicked on Cancel we should stop the execution.
How i can achieve this?

Below is my code:

```
function Verifivation() {
var messages = ['Custmer and Client is from Diff City'];
            var OKFunction = function () {
                $('#MessagesDialog').remove();
                return true;
            };
            var cancelFunction = function () {
                $('#MessagesDialog').remove();

            };
            createMessageDialog("Verification", "ReceptPage", messages, ["OK", "Cancel"], [OKFunction, cancelFunction], function () { }, null, null, getConfirmHandler);

}
function createMessageDialog(title, parentid, messages, buttonLabels, buttonFunctions, functPartialLoad, top, isModal, closeCallback) {
    if (top == null || top == '') top = 80;
    if (isModal == null) isModal = true;
    var openFunc = function () {
        if (typeof messages == "object") {
            if (messages.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                    $("#messages").append("<span>" + messages[i] + "</span><br/>");
                }
            }
        } else if (typeof messages == "string") {
            $("#messages").append("<span>" + messages + "</span><br/>");
        }

        if ((buttonLabels.length > 0) && (buttonFunctions.length > 0) && (buttonLabels.length == buttonFunctions.length)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < buttonLabels.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    $("#messageBtn").append("<button type='button' value='" + buttonLabels[i] + "'class='button green' id='" + buttonLabels[i].trim().replace(" ", "") + "Btn'><i class='fas fa-check-circle' style='margin-right: 3px !important'></i>" + buttonLabels[i].trim().replace(" ", "") + "</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                }
                else {
                    $("#messageBtn").append("<button type='button' value='" + buttonLabels[i] + "'class='button orange' id='" + buttonLabels[i].trim().replace(" ", "") + "Btn'><i class='fas fa-times-circle' style='margin-right: 3px !important'></i>" + buttonLabels[i].trim().replace(" ", "") + "</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                }
                $("#" + buttonLabels[i].trim().replace(" ", "") + "Btn").click(buttonFunctions[i]);
            }
        }
        functPartialLoad();
    };
    $("#" + parentid).append('<div id="MessagesDialog" title="' + title + '" style="display: none"><div id="messages"></div><div id="partialContent"></div><div id="messageBtn" style="margin-top: 5px; text-align:center;"></div></div>');
    $("#MessagesDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        heigt: 500,
        width: 500,
        position: ['top', top],
        modal: isModal,
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).remove();
            if (closeCallback)
                closeCallback();
        },
        open: openFunc
    })
}
```

Comment: Can't you just `return` when the user cancels? Or event better put it in an if-statement so the code only runs when the questions returns true?

Comment: Not sure what the problem here is:  `var OKFunction = function () { $('#MessagesDialog').remove(); continueWithProcess(); };`.

Comment: Don't think of it as "stopping" or "pausing" your function, but rather "do this, prompt, if yes do this"  ie split it into to two processes, what to do before confirmation and what to do on yes.

Comment: you can check the return from popup and the take effective action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  function openDialog() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: "auto",
      width: 400,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "OK": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          executeNow();
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  }
  function executeNow(){
    console.log("I am executing");
  };
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal confirmation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?" style="display:none;">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
 
<p onclick="openDialog()">click me to open dialog</p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's a asynchronous programming, don't worry about first and second, it will do parallelly

Comment: The code you've provided isn't async and there was no mention of async in OPs "it should continue the execution"

Comment: Also, there's no "parallel" javascript - javascript is single-threaded.

Comment: yes my "parallel" word is wrong, actually i want to say may be both will execute in same time, but what will happen if my executeNow() function look like: function executeNow(){
 setTimeout(function(){console.log("I am executing");},5000);
  };